# Resolving a "shared" secretsmanager secret in CloudFormation StackSet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

In AWS account A, I've created a secret in `secrets manager`, it's a key:value pair with the key `token`. I want to share this secret with any account under my AWS organization, so it has this resource-policy:

```
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Sid" : "policyForSomething",
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
      "AWS" : "*"
    },
    "Action" : "secretsmanager:*",
    "Resource" : "*",
    "Condition" : {
      "StringEquals" : {
        "aws:PrincipalOrgID" : "o-xxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

Where `o-xxxxxxxxxx` is my organization ID in AWS Organizations. As I understand this means that this secret can be accessed by any account in my AWS organization.

I want to pass a [dynamic-reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html) to this secret in a CloudFormation Stack**Set**, as a parameter to a lambda in a different AWS organization.

```
  MyCustomResource:
    Type: Custom::MyCustomResource
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: arn:aws:lambda:thatlambdasArn
      Token:
        !Join
          - ''
          - - '{{'
            - 'resolve:secretsmanager:'
            - 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789123:secret:MySecretName-otSgNu:'
            - 'SecretString:token::}}'
```

This resource is a lambda-backed resource. The AWS account invoking this lambda is part of my AWS organization, and therefore should have access to the secret. Please note I'm `!Join` using after trying all sorts of combinations, including:

```
Token: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789123:secret:MySecretName-otSgNu:SecretString:token::}}'
```

However, once I create a stack instance in a child account, it seems all I'm getting is that literal string, and CFN isn't even attempting to resolve the secret itself.

Are dynamic references like this not supported for StackSets? Is what I'm trying to do achievable?

**Notice:** Giving the lambda access to secrets manager is out of the question. The lambda is running in an account under an entirely different organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`secretsmanager` dynamic references not work with custom resources. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html):

> Dynamic references for secure values, such as secretsmanager, **aren't currently supported in custom resources**.

You have to fetch the secret from `secretsmanager` in your lambda function which defines the custom resource.

Comment: Silly silly me, I read "CloudFormation registry" on the "custom resources" link and thought they were only talking about CFN public custom types...is there anyway to resolve the token elsewhere in the template and pass it afterwards?

Comment: @zerohedge I'm not aware of such way.